# Flash AS3 Crashing After A Multiple Clicks - Argument Error - noSource error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arguments, kiosk

I have here, some AS3 that is used to create a 19 button interactive kiosk. It calls 20 different video_files to be played in an FLVPLayer. When one button is clicked, it draws the player and specifies the source.

Whats happening is on our PC, is our crazy-kid-test, where we click a few different buttons starting and stopping the videos, and after a few button presses the SWF crashes.

I've had Argument Errors (according to Adobe Scout)
I have a noSource error present in debugger (points to the `removeChild(movie_container);`
And a couple other seemingly random bugs/error messages.

Would someone mind taking a look at the code. Thank you. Note: Becauser it's some 500lines long I'll paste up to buttonTwo.

```
    import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import fl.video.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;


//Mouse.hide();

stop();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, timerHandler);

//===================== Primary Event Listeners ==========================//
buttonOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playVideoOne);
buttonTwo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playVideoTwo);

// Show buttons so users can click - cheaper than adding/removing 20 e:listeners
function showTheButtons(): void {
    buttonOne.visible = true;
    buttonTwo.visible = true;

}

// Hide buttons so users cant crazy-click resulting in massive slowdown - cheaper than adding/removing 20 e:listeners
function hideTheButtons(): void {
    buttonOne.visible = false;
    buttonTwo.visible = false;

}

// ADD ALL EVENT Listeners after AttractLoop removed

//=====================
var attractTimer: Timer = new Timer(300000); //should be 7min OR 420000ms in production
attractTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler, false, 0, true);
attractTimer.start();
//=====================

this.aLoopMovie.visible = false;

aLoopMovie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);
function stopRemoveVideo(event: Event): void {
    showTheButtons();
    aLoopMovie.visible = false;
    aLoopMovie.gotoAndStop(1);
    //=====================
    attractTimer.start();
    //=====================
}

function timerHandler(event: Event): void {
    attractTimer.stop();
    hideTheButtons();
    //++
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, timerHandler);
    //++
    if (this.aLoopMovie.visible != true) {
        this.aLoopMovie.visible = true;
        this.aLoopMovie.play();
    }
}

//////////// BUILD PLAYER ///////////////
var movie_container: MovieClip = new MovieClip();

function launchVideo(vBox, vFile): void {
    hideTheButtons();

    var flvPlayer: FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();

    flvPlayer.source = vFile;
    flvPlayer.skinAutoHide = true;
    flvPlayer.skinBackgroundColor = 0x000000;

    flvPlayer.width = 1920;
    flvPlayer.height = 1080;
    flvPlayer.autoRewind = true;

    vBox.addChild(flvPlayer);

    // Allow Playabck timer //
    var playbackTimer: Timer = new Timer(5000); //should be 2sec OR 2000ms in production
    playbackTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, allowPlayback);
    function allowPlayback(event: Event): void {
        playbackTimer.stop();
        movie_container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);

        function stopRemoveVideo(event: Event): void {
            showTheButtons();
            flvPlayer.stop();
            //=====================
            movie_container.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);
            //=====================
            removeChild(movie_container);
            attractTimer.start();
        }

        flvPlayer.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        function completeHandler(event: fl.video.VideoEvent): void {
            flvPlayer.stop();
            playbackTimer.stop();
            showTheButtons();
            flvPlayer.removeEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            //=====================
            removeChild(movie_container);
            //=====================
            attractTimer.start();
        }
    }
    playbackTimer.start();
    //////////////////////////

}
//////////// END BUILD PLAYER ///////////////

//===================== Primary Functions
function playVideoOne(event: Event): void {

    //=====================
    attractTimer.stop();
    hideTheButtons();
    //=====================

    // Place container on stage
    addChild(movie_container);
    movie_container.x = 0;
    movie_container.y = 0;

    //Video Source
    var video_file = "MPVideos/MP-01.mp4";

    launchVideo(movie_container, video_file);
}

function playVideoTwo(event: Event): void {

    //=====================
    attractTimer.stop();
    hideTheButtons();
    //=====================

    // Place container on stage
    addChild(movie_container);
    movie_container.x = 0;
    movie_container.y = 0;

    //Video Source
    var video_file = "MPVideos/MP-02.mp4";

    launchVideo(movie_container, video_file);

}
```

**Updated**

```
function playVideoOne(event: Event): void {

    //=====================
    attractTimer.stop();
    hideTheButtons();
    //=====================

    var movie_container: MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    // Place container on stage
    addChild(movie_container);
    movie_container.x = 0;
    movie_container.y = 0;

    //Video Source
    var video_file = "MPVideos/MP-01.mp4";
    var flvPlayer: FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();

    function launchVideo(vBox, vFile): void {

        flvPlayer.source = vFile;
        flvPlayer.skinAutoHide = true;
        flvPlayer.skinBackgroundColor = 0x000000;

        flvPlayer.width = 1920;
        flvPlayer.height = 1080;
        flvPlayer.autoRewind = true;

        vBox.addChild(flvPlayer);

    }

    flvPlayer.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    function completeHandler(event: fl.video.VideoEvent): void {
        flvPlayer.stop();
        flvPlayer.closeVideoPlayer(0);
        showTheButtons();
        flvPlayer.removeEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        //=====================
        attractTimer.start();
        //=====================
        removeChild(movie_container);
        //=====================
    }

    movie_container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);
    function stopRemoveVideo(event: Event): void {
        flvPlayer.stop();
        flvPlayer.closeVideoPlayer(0);
        showTheButtons();
        removeChild(movie_container);
        //=====================
        attractTimer.start();
        //=====================
        movie_container.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);
        //=====================

    }

    launchVideo(movie_container, video_file);
}
```

Moved the nested functions up a level. These event listeners (Complete & CLICK) don't work outside of the of the playVideoOne function.

Comment: I think after skiming your code that there is a problem with the closurefunctions in `allowPlayback`. Write the inside functions `stopRemoveVideo`and `completeHandler` as normal class-methods.

Comment: 3 levels of inner methods???? ... I give up already.

Comment: @botMaster I moved them up a level, so now they're not three levels need. though, they are still 2 levels deep.

Comment: @AndreLehnert when I move 'stopRemoveVideo' and 'completeHandler' out of the 'playVideoOne' function, I get this... 'Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 149, Column 2 1120: Access of undefined property flvPlayer.' same for 'movie_container'

Comment: Heres the full code - http://pastebin.com/jjBPbXHQ

Comment: Have a look at vespers answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary mistake is that you declare a variable in a function in order for it to be used in a nested function. These don't work as you think, and actually I doubt this is not a described type of undefined behavior. And, you have a lot of function designed this way. What you should instead do is: Have `flvPlayer` be a variable at the top level, initialized in an event listener, with corresponding event listeners to clear the player, and relocate `function launchVideo(vBox, vFile)` to the top level as well - these perfectly duplicate in each of your listeners. Also you should wrap the common part of all the listeners into a parameterized function that will create the `movie_container` and use the provided string to launch a correct video.

```
//===================== Additional variables
var flvPlayer:FLVPlayback;
var movie_container:MovieClip;

//===================== Primary Functions
function playVideoByString(source:String):void {
    attractTimer.stop();
    hideTheButtons();
    movie_container = new MovieClip();
    addChild(movie_container);
    movie_container.x = 0;
    movie_container.y = 0;

    launchVideo(movie_container, source); // that's it
}

function playVideoOne(event: Event): void {
    playVideoByString("MPVideos/MP-01.mp4"); // that's it as well
}
```

Now, you don't handle proper removal of `FLVPlayback` instance, they have listeners so it's them that clog your memory. Leaking even an `Object` is already detrimental, and you are leaking a whole video player. It's no surprise that you run out of memory this quick. So you have to properly stop and detach the video player either if a new button is pressed, or the player completes playback. According to your update of the question, you have functions devised to do this, and to make them work, you just need the variables at the global level. But your mistake is that you add two listeners when initializing, but remove only one at either of the removal functions - the other listener remains and prevent either the `movie_container` or the `flvPlayer` to be garbage collected, effectively leaking a whole video player instance.

```
// Primary functions (cont.)
function stopRemoveVideo(event: Event): void {
    doCleanup();
}
function completeHandler(event: fl.video.VideoEvent): void {
    doCleanup();
}
function doCleanup():void {
    // these actions are common between handlers, so put em in one place
    flvPlayer.stop();
    flvPlayer.closeVideoPlayer(0);
    showTheButtons();
    removeChild(movie_container);
    attractTimer.start();
    movie_container.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);
    flvPlayer.removeEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    // clear the references just in case
    movie_container=null;
    flvPlayer=null;
    // you need to remove both listeners in either case, otherwise you leak objects!
}
function launchVideo(vBox, vFile): void {
    flvPlayer=new FLVPlayback();
    flvPlayer.source = vFile;
    flvPlayer.skinAutoHide = true;
    flvPlayer.skinBackgroundColor = 0x000000;

    flvPlayer.width = 1920;
    flvPlayer.height = 1080;
    flvPlayer.autoRewind = false; // this changes as well
    // you close the vid if you hit movie end, why allow the player to autorewind?

    vBox.addChild(flvPlayer);
    // adding listeners in here
    flvPlayer.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    movie_container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopRemoveVideo);
}
```

This might probably be not enough to eliminate all mistakes in your source, but it should give you a good start in how to optimize your application and functions that use objects instantiated in one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'll give it another once over and start rewriting my code based on your explanation. I can't thank you enough, all of your for that matter. Much appreciated. Owe you a few beers ;)

Comment: I gave your code a try (http://pastebin.com/BTNmh0jC) and I keep getting an error. 'TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at NMAH_MP_Interactive_3_0_fla::MainTimeline/launchVideo()
 at NMAH_MP_Interactive_3_0_fla::MainTimeline/playVideoByString()
 at NMAH_MP_Interactive_3_0_fla::MainTimeline/playVideoOne()
'

Comment: Weird too because it's LaunchVideo is present `launchVideo(movie_container, source);`

Comment: Missed `new FLVPlayback()` in that function. Fixed. (This is what comes if one can't test the code. Expect this from elsewhere.)

Comment: Looks like ` flvPlayer.source = vFile;` is causing the error. Even though the source is being passed by playVideoByString `launchVideo(movie_container, source);`

Comment: AH! I see what you did. I'll be back. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I commented out the `flvPlayer.closeVideoPlayer(0);` line and it seems to build now without errors. I'll check with Scout.

Comment: Still working on it. it was throwing an error because I had commented out the show/hide buttons. I'm still showing some net streams active, one for ever button/FLV played. I suspect it's due to the FLVplayer not being completely removed. I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: Hmm.. Still crashing after tons of clicks. I think commenting this out `flvPlayer.closeVideoPlayer(0);` is whats causing it. Though flash throws an error when I try to remove the player. Latest Code http://pastebin.com/BTNmh0jC

Comment: [The manual on FLVPlayback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#closeVideoPlayer%28%29) states that you cannot close the video player at (0), instead check for `visibleVideoPlayerIndex` and `activeVideoPlayerIndex` properties, if either is nonzero, close that one.

Comment: Tried tracing the index.. `function doCleanup():void {
    flvPlayer.stop();
 trace(flvPlayer.activeVideoPlayerIndex);
 trace(flvPlayer.visibleVideoPlayerIndex);` and index returned is `0`

Comment: Try getting the video player prior to calling `stop()` and closing its netstream. `var vp:VideoPlayer=flvPlayback.getVideoPlayer(flvPlayback.activeVideoPlayerIndex); vp.netStream.close()`

Comment: You're the man! Thank you so much for your help. I wish I could send you a beer (or 10).

Comment: Do some charity if you like, that'll be better than a beer (I don't drink beer :))

Comment: I'm unable to get the project to crash, however the test appliance this runs on does crash when the `attractLoop` plays and the user comes back and clicks a bunch of times. This is only after multiple "bongo" tests  It took 10 times what it used to take to crash the app. I did notice that I wasn't removing the timerHandler listener, so I added a `removeListener` to the `launchVideo` method. I'm also adding the listener back in `doCleanup` - seems to be working well. Though I wonder if there is something else leaking. Is there any way to test for that?

Comment: There is Adobe Scout, you can check for the number of objects allocated by type, so if something grows when the app is normally working and does not find the ceiling, and is of some class that you instantiate, dig around that code.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I took at look at the memory profile and found a dip that matched where the memory returns to after a video is closed. The dip coincided with `attractTimer` leading me to trace the total number of times attract timer started at using `trace(attractTimer.currentCount);` and it look like that number is `0`. Leading me to believe that the timer is also leaking. I'll see what else it might be. If interested here is the full code as it stands today. You'll definitely notice some of your significant contributions. http://pastebin.com/BTNmh0jC

Comment: Listening on a cue point, and adding a listener in that listener? You will leak a `movie_container` and an empty `flvPlayer` if the video would have more than one cue point. `removeEventListener` removes only one listener from an object, but multiple listeners, even multiple copies of the same listener can be added, this results in a certain code running more than once. About `attractTimer` - unlikely, as when you test, you probably don't wait whole 5 minutes for the timer to ever tick, and calling `stop()` then `start()` makes the timer to start its 300k counting from zero again.

Comment: Hmm.. I added the cue point to prevent rapid fire clicking, forcing the user to wait a second before dismissing the video. I am waiting the full 300k on the test appliance, however when testing locally, I set the timer to 5k.  Listening for a single cue point will leak a full player even though I'm removing it in the subsequent function?

Comment: If there is one cue point, no it shouldn't, but you might have other cue points read from somewhere. You might query `if (movie_container.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK)) return;` in that `cp_listener` so that you won't add superfluous listeners to `movie_container`.

Comment: Looking into more memory profiling. Seems like there is still some netstreams active, (3 actually) after one button is clicked and dismissed. I'll admit, I have no idea what I'm looking for in Scout. Other than the memory usage and time/ms theres a lot of data there.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I managed to eliminate NetStream issues thanks to the help provided by Vesper and Andrew. Instead of using NetStreams `close();` method, I used `dispose();` to flush the `NetStream buffers` thus effectively eliminating what appeared to be a memory leak. A Special thanks to Vesper for providing an awesome example of code from which I was able to significantly improve my project.